# How can I model an Algebraic Data Type that describes a relationship between members of itself, except for when it is self-related?

Tags: kotlin, algebraic-data-types

I'm learning about Algebraic Data Types (very recently), and how they can be used to prevent irrepresentable types.

I need to model a relationship between two directions (North, East, South, West).

All combinations are valid, except for when it is combined with itself.

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| Left  | Right | Valid   |
+-------+-------+---------+
| North | North | Invalid |
| North | East  | Valid   |
| North | South | Valid   |
| North | West  | Valid   |
+-------+-------+---------+
| East  | North | Valid   |
| East  | East  | Invalid |
| East  | South | Valid   |
| East  | West  | Valid   |
+-------+-------+---------+
| South | North | Valid   |
| South | East  | Valid   |
| South | South | Invalid |
| South | West  | Valid   |
+-------+-------+---------+
| West  | North | Valid   |
| West  | East  | Valid   |
| West  | South | Valid   |
| West  | West  | Invalid |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

From what I understand, we might be able to structure the type system by looking at the algebra. Here, there are 16 total combinations, and 12 valid combinations (`4 * 4` or `4 * 3`). Since there are 4 Directions, that seems to imply that there needs to another type that only has 3 values.

This seems to be a Product type. The number of combinations is a result of multiplication.

Through some mental gymnastics, I was able to come up with something that seems to work, but is very hard to read.

```kotlin
sealed interface Direction

sealed interface NotNorth
sealed interface NotEast
sealed interface NotSouth
sealed interface NotWest

object North : Direction, NotEast, NotSouth, NotWest
object East : Direction, NotNorth, NotSouth, NotWest
object South : Direction, NotNorth, NotEast, NotWest
object West : Direction, NotNorth, NotEast, NotSouth

typealias EntranceFromNorth = Pair<North, NotNorth>
typealias EntranceFromEast = Pair<East, NotEast>
typealias EntranceFromSouth = Pair<South, NotSouth>
typealias EntranceFromWest = Pair<West, NotWest>

//val NorthNorth = EntranceFromNorth(North, North)// compilation error
val NorthEast = EntranceFromNorth(North, East)
val NorthSouth = EntranceFromNorth(North, South)
val NorthWest = EntranceFromNorth(North, West)

val EastNorth = EntranceFromEast(East, North)
//val EastEast = EntranceFromEast(East, East)// compilation error
val EastSouth = EntranceFromEast(East, South)
val EastWest = EntranceFromEast(East, West)

val SouthNorth = EntranceFromSouth(South, North)
val SouthEast = EntranceFromSouth(South, East)
//val SouthSouth = EntranceFromSouth(South, South)// compilation error
val SouthWest = EntranceFromSouth(South, West)

val WestNorth = EntranceFromWest(West, North)
val WestEast = EntranceFromWest(West, East)
val WestSouth = EntranceFromWest(West, South)
//val WestWest = EntranceFromWest(West, West)// compilation error
```

Is there a better way I can model this type of relationship with the type system?

The parts that feel awkward to me are

- Multiple `Not*` types. It feels like types should be inclusionary, not exclusionary, but I'm not sure how to build up an inclusive type that models this.
- I'm not sure if this is really representative of an ADT, because I'm only recently aware of its existence.
- I'm wondering if it is preferable to have an explicit Invalid type, so that there's no confusion about if Invalid types exist, or if it was mistakenly omitted (changing the solution to have 16 possible states, instead of 12).

Comment: I don't think it's particularly hard to read. What part about it do you not like?

Comment: @Sweeper it may be my low exposure to this type of thinking, but it feels awkward to have multiple `Not*` types. Additionally, I'm not sure if this is really representative of an ADT, because I'm only recently aware of its existence. Also, I'm wondering if it is preferable to have an explicit Invalid type, so that there's no confusion about if Invalid types exist, or if it was mistakenly omitted.

Comment: How about thinking about this another way, and represent this as a direction + a direction _to turn to_? For example, `NorthLeft` would be `NorthWest`, `EastRight` would be `EastSouth`, and `SouthBackwards` would be `SouthNorth`. The direction to turn can only be `Left`, `Right` or `Backwards`, and there's no `GoStraight` to avoid e.g. `NorthNorth`. Does that stray too much from your use case?

Comment: @Sweeper no, it doesn't stray too much, although in my use case, it's the reverse. These directions represent Entrance and Exit points through Rooms. This is a one-way traversal, with backward being where they entered the room. So `North goStraight` would lead to the South exit. Additionally, it provides some extra clarity, "you cannot go backward". I really like that solution.

Comment: @Sweeper It's not "Starting at one of four directions, there are three (out of four) directions you can find an exit", but rather "Start at one of four directions, you can go one of three ways". Turning naturally has three values in this domain, left, right, straight. It's really clean, and simple to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

> These directions represent Entrance and Exit points through Rooms. This is a one-way traversal, with backward being where they entered the room.

In that case, rather than modelling the exit as an absolute cardinal direction, you can model it as one of the relative directions to the entrance direction, either on the left, right, or in front. The exit direction doesn't include a "backwards", so you can't exit from where you came.

```
sealed interface EntranceDirection
sealed interface ExitDirection

object North : EntranceDirection
object East : EntranceDirection
object South : EntranceDirection
object West : EntranceDirection

object Left : ExitDirection
object Right : ExitDirection
object Front : ExitDirection

typealias RoomTraversalSegment = Pair<EntranceDirection, ExitDirection>
```

Actually, two enums would have done the job too:

```
enum class EntranceDirection {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
}

enum class ExitDirection {
    LEFT, RIGHT, FRONT
}
```